# Sound mysteriously gone missing (lubuntu 14.04 32bit)

Tags: 14.04, sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

I am running Lubuntu 14.04 on a non-sse2 machine (amd duron 1800).
Strangely, right after installation there was no sound at all even though ALSA was present and my sound card detected and installed (C-Media CMI8738). Later I realized pulseaudio was missing, after installation of which I got the sound. As I kept installing various software sound went missing again. Not sure why or when it happened. Reinstallation of pulseaudio did not help. I suspect it might have happened after I installed pipelight.
Whatever happened, here's the report on the current state of matters:
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=b9f4cc8ebcf9020387726c5b314e33c19d346a16
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your alsa-info, the "phone" fader is off (muted): try to unmute it in Alsamixer : launch alsamixer in a terminal, scroll to "phone" with arrow right key , change state fader pressing "m" or space bar.

If it stills bad, you can also try to use pavucontrol (Pulse audio volume control) and try various selections in the "output devices" tab and "profiles" tab.

Comment: It works. Cheers. Changing the output device helped.